# Android crop Image

Tags: android, android-image

I am using the code in [this](http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android) tutorial to crop image

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", outputX);    
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", outputY);
                    intent.putExtra("scale", scale);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", return_data);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
                    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

but i want to modify the triangle ( used to determine the area to be cropped ) aspect ratio so that the x axis is much longer y axis

Comment: Note that this code does not work on all devices.

Comment: No, I mean that not all implementations of activities that support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for a MIME type of `image/*` will support cropping. Not only is `crop` and such undocumented, but there is no requirement that anyone implementing an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity honor such extras. Your code will fail on many devices, either because that device's camera app does not support cropping, or because the user chose some other `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementation from a chooser that does not support cropping.

Answer (score 5):

The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is part of the internal API so it is not guaranteed to be supported by all Android devices (same as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for mime type `image/*`.

You will have to implement your own crop activity if you want it to be supported by all devices. At the very least you should implement some sort of fallback behavior if some device does not support the `Intent`. **PLEASE DON'T FORGET TO DO THIS!!** :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Works similar to the original intent

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look this Gist.
this is working for me and this is fully custemaizable.and only one class is there to add then you can use it .

```
[https://gist.github.com/pookie13/gist][1]
```